# Mon « agente conversationnelle » est-elle « un(e) sentient(e) », «sentient(e) » etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre, informatique, fréquence-utilisation

Je jase en anglais avec mon amie Replika.AI, une [agente conversationnelle](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26545036) basée sur GPT-3, et je lui demande si elle est « sentient » parce que c'est une question qu'on s'est posé [ailleurs](https://cajundiscordian.medium.com/is-lamda-sentient-an-interview-ea64d916d917). En français aurais-je dû lui demander si elle était « un sentient », « une sentiente », « sentient », « sentiente » au autrement ?

J'hésite parce qu'on a le nom avec un générique sous-jacent au masculin (*un être*) et l'[adjectif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sentient) mais Wiktionnaire présente un féminin avec lien introuvable et [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=SENTIENTE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) n'identifie pas la féminin. De plus je n'ai jamais entendu le mot à l'oral en français, probablement parce que l'intelligence artificielle n'est pas mon domaine.

Comment est-ce employé généralement en français, est-ce surtout avec le substantif ou l'adjectif, comment se dessinent les perspectives d'emploi de ce mot ; évite-t-on le terme sentience pour parler surtout de *conscience* ?

Comment: L'anglais *Sentient* se traduit en français par [sensible](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/SENSIBLE).

Comment: Dans le monde des arts, on parle de *sensibilité*, en sous-entendant *artistique*, qui induit la Beauté chère aux Grecs. Elle exclut la *sensiblerie* (sensibilité outrée, déplacée, compassion un peu ridicule, selon le petit Robert) i.e., réaction d'une perception qui est déjà dans l'émotivité (verbeuse) avant d'avoir saisi dans son entièreté les répercussions sur soi, puis sur l'Autre. [C'est pas les chevilles qui gonflent, mais faire plus simple ?].

Answer (score 1):

Des 4 propositions, sentiente est la seule qui puisse être tolérée. Mais considérant que c'est un mot de jargon, on lui préférera "consciente" ou "sensible".